# Set Devtools Protocol event listener in DevTools-on-DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

In DevTools-on-DevTools it's possible to run DevTools protocol commands like this:

```
let Main = await import('./devtools-frontend/front_end/entrypoints/main/main.js');
await Main.MainImpl.sendOverProtocol('Network.enable');
```

(https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#monitor)

In a Chrome extension it's possible to listen to the protocol events like this: `chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(eventHandler);`

Is there a similar way to attach a custom function to the protocol events in DevTools-on-DevTools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the [source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/core/protocol_client/InspectorBackend.ts;l=227-235;drc=9e32f692eac2cace1840537d90cc1dea53465c82), there are `onMessageSent` and `onMessageReceived` hooks:

```js
(await import('./devtools-frontend/front_end/core/protocol_client/protocol_client.js'))
  .InspectorBackend.test.onMessageSent = (msg, target) => { /* do something */ }
```